# Trying to pull data by TODAY date to another sheet (multiple lines of same date to multiple lines on new sheet

Tags: excel

Basically I am trying to pull off a sheet that is filled by date and has multiple teams on that date by their schedule..
I want it to return those teams only if it is todays date.

example and sorry if I don't describe well

Database sheet has several dates with several teams listed. I want to take everything from 1 date and move those teams in order to the date -to  sheet

So for example 2/12/2021 Denver
2/12/2021 UTAH
and so on
to the new sheet into column A and B in the same order as it is on the database sheet

[Database Sheet example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rxpl.png)

[Date -to sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LVRU.png)

Comment: Please see [ask] and [reprex]... include your current attempt. Also, is that Excel or Google Sheets? There's a different tag for each.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should create 2 sheets the way I did. You should view the pictures I added below. The sheet named "Database" will be filled by you, but the sheet named "Date-to" will be automatically filled by the code every time you open this excel. In the photo it is already filled because I executed it according to today's date. All you need to do is copy and paste the first column which includes column names. All rows and columns will be in their exact locations, otherwise the code may not work :)

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gt4FK.jpg)

[Date-to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFa4N.jpg)

Then you should add a macro to achieve your goal, I will explain how to add it. If you know to use VBA you can skip this part:

From "Developer" tab, click on "Visual Basic". Then, click these in order: Insert , Module. Then you should paste the code below.

I hope It works, if you face any problem we can contact again. (Don't forget to save this file in macro-enabled ".xlsm" format!)

Note: If you review the code, in two places I wrote "1000". You can modify this number according to your total row number. I used 1000 to protect my computer from extra running problems :)

Have a nice day.

---

```
Sub Auto_Open()

For i = 2 To 1000

Sheets("Date-to").Rows(i).Clear

Next

Sheets("Database").Activate

For i = 2 To 1000

    If Cells(i, 1) = Date Then
    
        Rows(i).Copy
        Sheets("Date-to").Activate
        Range("A60000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
        Sheets("Database").Activate
        
    End If
    
Next

Sheets("Database").Activate

Rows(1).Select

End Sub
```

---